Elasticsearch: How to get list of devices that haven't communicated recently?
I'm trying to get a list of devices that have not communicated in the last 30 minutes. I think my search needs to be:

Separate index by name of device.
Get latest record for each device.
List records that are older than 30 mins.

The first two I can achieve by collapsing the index by the enum of the device Name, then sorting them by time and only returning the latest:
GET /<index>/_search
{
  "collapse": {
    "field": "Name.enum",
    "inner_hits": {
      "name": "most_recent",
      "size": 1,
      "sort": [{
        "Time": {
          "order": "desc"
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

But now want to query which of these is over 30 mins old:
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": {
        "range": {
          "Time": {
            "gt": "now-35m"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

How can I run the query on the result of the sort after the collapse?

I would do it differently, not by using field collapsing, but using a terms aggregation instead, which gives you more flexibility.
In the aggregation query below, you can see that we're aggregating the devices names, then we're taking the most recent record (using a max metric aggregation) and finally, we're weeding out all buckets whose most recent record is older than 35 minutes ago by leveraging the bucket_selector pipeline aggregation:
POST <index>/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "devices": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Name.enum"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "most_recent": {
          "max": {
            "field": "Time"
          }
        },
        "older_than_30_min": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "most_recent": "most_recent"
            },
            "script": "params.most_recent > new Date().getTime() - 35 * 60000"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

If you're on recent versions (8.11+), you can also leverage the newly released and very promising ES|QL language which makes that kind of queries much easier:
POST _query
{
  "query": """
  from index
  | stats most_recent = max(Time) by Name
  | where most_recent > NOW() - 35 minutes
  | keep Name, most_recent
  | limit 100
  """
}

The results look something like this
{
  "columns": [
    {
      "name": "Name",
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    {
      "name": "most_recent",
      "type": "date"
    }
  ],
  "values": [
    [
      "John Doe",
      "2024-04-13T04:25:10.000Z"
    ]
  ]
}


That's great, thanks. Any idea how I can apply that to a map so the markers change colour when they're offline?

Cool, glad it helped! I'd suggest you post another question with more background info concerning your map needs.

Turns out that although these work you can't use them anywhere in the UI.

Which one do you mean? And on which version are you?

V8.13.2. I can't use the aggs keyword in Discover and ES|QL appears differently in the dashboard.

In Discover you can use ES|QL

But when you use ES|QL to create a table there's no "Directly filter on click" option.

I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean, maybe let's create a new question to discuss about this, since this one is solved.

@Val's answer is correct but at the current time (Elastic v8.13.2) neither of these solutions work properly for visualisation:

"aggs" can't be used in Discover.
ES|QL can but doesn't have a "Directly filter on click" option.
Neither can be used on Maps.

If you want to visualise this then you can setup a transform and apply a KQL filter to it which works everywhere.
If you want to use the result in a map then you'll need to setup the GeoJSON mapping first (since GeoJSON isn't dynamically mapped - see Dynamic field mapping):

Click the drop down menu on the LHS and go to Search -> Overview then select Indices.
Click "Create a new index" and give it a name.
Go to Management -> Dev Tools.
Get the name of your GeoJSON field and set it to "geo_point":

    PUT /<new index name>/_mapping
    {
      "properties": {
        "<your GeoJSON field>": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        }
      }
    }

Now to setup the transform:

Go to Management -> Stack Management and select Data -> Transforms.
Click "Create a transform"
Select your source.
Select "Latest" at the top.
Set "Time range". You can just "Use full data" but I set it to 30 days so I'm not searching my entire history.
Set "Unique Keys" to "Name.enum" or whatever you use to identify your individual devices.
Set "Sort field" to "Time" or whatever your timestamp is.
Click Next.
Set "Transform ID" to the same as the index you defined earlier.
Make sure "Use transform ID as destination index name" is on.
Make sure "Create data view" is on.
Make sure "Continuous mode" is on.
Set "Data field for continuous mode" is set to "Time".
Click Next.
Click "Create and start".
You should see your transform appear in the list with Status "started". Click on the three buttons to the right and select "View in Discover".
You can now set the KQL filter at the top to NOT Time > now-35m to filter devices that haven't been seen in the last 35 minutes.

You can use this same filter in Visualisations and Maps. If you want different Map layers for active and missing devices then use different layers with different colours.
